# How to keep user's activity log on a website?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I'm working on an website that is going to need to log user activity - things like user1 has logged in, user2 has updated a thing called ABC and keep these into database. I'm looking for some source code and description. I'm newbie and learning web development by myself. I've searched a lot but not getting good answer about it.

Comment: You are purely logging server-side actions, right? So no `user clicked on x` etc?

Comment: Brother I want to capture user's all actions even his/her clicks on any content.

Comment: You already got good answers regarding the server side / database. Now, if you want to log events originating purely on the client side (such as 'clicked a button' - look up "JavaScript Event Handlers" on how to capture them), you need to use a JavaScript technique called AJAX to send those events to the server (communicating via websockets is an alternative).

Comment: Thank u brother.

Answer (score 0):

I would write a singleton `Logger` with a`static` `method` `Logger::logUserAction($actionType, $actionParams)`. 
The nethod would insert a new record in a db table [action int, params text, date timestamp].

Comment: Brother thanks for ur comment but my main problem is I don't know how to catch the user actions or generate log like userX downloaded a song using the function. Is there any source code or tutorial that explained that topic?

Comment: You have to add a call to Logger::logUserAction in every place where iser makes an action. I am not aware of an automated solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

For a basic logger, first, you should decide if you need a log on the database or in a file format. If a log would be in database, you need to create a database table that will receive the log.

In both cases you need to create a function that will generate the log. Test this function alone before putting it on your website.

Once done you should call this function on your web structure, on login, on database changes (to log object changes), and so on.

A log function can be a `static` function called from your PHP files or even a log class if you are using OO architecture.

There are more advanced log features specially if you are using frameworks like [zend.log](https://framework.zend.com/manual/2.1/en/modules/zend.log.overview.html) or [Laravel logging](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/errors#logging), but you did not give too much information about your web app.

OBS: This approach works for server side logging. To log client actions (user clicked something) you would need an AJAX call to the server to call the log function.

Comment: Brother thanks for ur comment but my main problem is I don't know how to catch the user actions or generate log using the function. Is there any source code or tutorial that explained that topic?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this in many ways.

For login/logout activities, you can create a table in database called "login_activities"
where you can store data about certain login/logout activity.
You would probably need columns like:

user_id (int) - the id of the user who logged in or out

date_and_time (datetime) - date and time at which user logged in or out

user_ip (varchar) - ip from which user logged in or out

activity_name (varchar) - this could take for example values "login" and "logout" and will indicate if user logged in or logged out

Ex.

### id | user_id | date_and_time         | user_ip   | activity_name

1 |        1           |   2017-17-03 12:00:00 | 192.168.0.1 | LOGIN

2 |        1             |   2017-17-03 12:15:00 | 192.168.0.1 | LOGOUT

The first row in the table will let you know that user with the id "1", logged in at 2017-17-03 at 12h from ip 192.168.0.1.
The second row will indicate that the user with the id "1" logged out at 2017-17-03 at 12:15h from ip 192.168.0.1.

Create this table in your database and then in your code where you handle user logins,
if the user login was successfull you can have a php code like this which will get the needed data.

```
$user_id = $_SESSION['user_id']; // if you stored users id into session and i suppose you did
$user_ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; // will give you the ip address from which the user logged in
```

Then you can execute the following sql statement to insert the data into login_activities table:
(This is a simple example - use PDO or any other method to prevent SQL injection!!!)

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO login_activities(user_id, date_and_time, user_ip, activity_name) VALUES($user_id, NOW(), $user_ip, 'LOGIN'");
```

And after the user clicks on logout button on your page and get successfully logged out, before actually unseting his session, you can pull the user id and ip from the same way as above, and execute the following sql statement to insert the data into login_activities table:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO login_activities(user_id, date_and_time, user_ip, activity_name) VALUES($user_id, NOW(), $user_ip, 'LOGOUT'");
```

As for the updates, this is a little bit more specific and i would need a little more info about your project to give you more usefull info, but i would recommend using database triggers for that.

Triggers allow you to execute some sql inside your db when certain events occur (SELECT, UPDATE, INSERT, DELETE).

I would recommend you to read a few articles about database triggers, beacuse the concept is not really too hard to grasp and is very usefull for those situations when you want to keep logs in your database and much more!

Comment: Brother thanks for your comment. I know the database insertion procedure. I'm on how to capture the user's actions what is he/she clicking,what is he/she downloading, what is he/she updating. How the code will be?? And I also know the $_SESSION["user_id"] and also know the $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] coz it's available on internet but codes for capturing the user actions is not available(or maybe I'm not getting the right one).

Comment: Well if you want to code it on your own, first thing that comes to my mind is  adding a onclick event to every element on your site which will get the elements id, value and everything else you need, and using ajax call a php script to save this info into database, later on, based on clicks you can see what the user clicked on at what time. But i dont think this is a great approach especially if you have many users at your website, also there are some free to tools use like Google Analytics or Clicky and many others that can do the thing you wanna  make.